# MySQL; ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE doesn't work vice versa

Tags: php, mysql, date, sql-order-by

This is my code:

`SELECT id, title, date FROM table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date,"%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s")`

The date output is:

```
2016-12-11 14:40:00
2016-11-15 08:50:09
2016-11-15 08:54:58
```

`SELECT id, title, date FROM table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date,"%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s") DESC`
doesn't work for me for some reason.

How can I reach to ORDER BY this?

```
2016-11-15 08:54:58
2016-11-15 08:50:09
2016-12-11 14:40:00
```

**Edit: `date` is stored as `timestamp` in my MySQL database!**

Comment: Why are your dates stored as strings?

Comment: The order you're trying to achieve is just wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: my `date`s are stored as `timestamp`.

Comment: Have you tried ordering by date/time part? It seems you want to order by date _ascending_ and time _descending_.

Comment: Try `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` instead of `STR_TO_DATE(date,"%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s")`

Comment: @Gvidas Still doesn't work. Output now is: `2016-11-15 08:50:09`
`2016-11-15 08:54:58` `2016-12-11 14:40:00`

Comment: @user7128548 So that's looks ok if you're not using `DESC`. `SELECT id, title, date FROM table ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)` should return `2016-11-15 08:50:09 2016-11-15 08:54:58 2016-12-11 14:40:00` and `SELECT id, title, date FROM table ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) DESC` should return `2016-12-11 14:40:00 2016-11-15 08:54:58 2016-11-15 08:50:09`

Comment: @Gvidas But it's still the wrong order, it should also order by the time, not only the date.

Comment: @user7128548 I don't understand why it makes no sense :D *ASC* order of your timestamps are: `2016-11-15 08:50:09 2016-11-15 08:54:58 2016-12-11 14:40:00` and *DESC* order is: `2016-12-11 14:40:00 2016-11-15 08:54:58 2016-11-15 08:50:09`

Comment: If it's already a timestamp then you don't need str_to_date at all. Just order by date

Comment: @Gvidas, weigreen found the solution.

Comment: @Strawberry Also didn't work, but weigreen already found the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you want the data that order by **date ascending and time descending.**

You can try this:

```
SELECT id, title, date 
FROM  table 
ORDER BY DATE(date) ASC , TIME(date) DESC
```